# MD5 hashing using union for struct types

Tags: c, md5, unions

I was wondering if using union command to do a MD5 hash is recommended?
the reason I want to use union is because I want do hash a structure like the following.

```
struct Body{
    int commandType;
    char data[MaxLine];
};

union UBody{
    Body    body;
    char    str[MaxLine + 4];
}
```

since `#include <openssl/md5.h>` requires char type this is the only thing I could think of. please let me know.

Comment: Notice that `union` is *not* a *command* in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the checksum of some in-memory data you could cast the pointer to that data to `(char*)` and pass it to `MD5`:

```
struct yourstruct_st data;

char md5[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
MD5((const unsigned char*)&data, sizeof(data), md5);
```

Beware that the compiler can add [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) to your `struct` (or `union` etc...) - and might not initialize the padding bytes. To have reproducible checksums, you need to be sure that all the bytes (including padding) of your memory zone are well defined. For example, if the zone is `malloc`-ed you should zero *all* of it (with `memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(*ptr));`) before filling it.

Of course the in-memory representation of some `struct` is specific to your processor and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (and depends upon the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), etc...). So the in-memory MD5 can be different on different machines.